# Keeping DOM Object in Memory Vs String HTML in Memory for repeated use

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory-management

I'm creating a plug and play chat module which loads (via ajax) a chatbox html as string. This html string has some elements which are hidden(display:none) and are to be used repetitively. eg:

```
<div class="chatboxmain">
 <div class="incomingmsg" style="display:none;">
 <div>
  <span class="msgtext"></span>
  <span class="msgtime"></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="outgoingmsg" style="display:none;">
 <div>
 <span class="msgtext"></span>
 <span class="msgtime"></span>
 </div>
 </div></div>
<!-- .....So on 5 types of messages contact,video,image -->
<div class="incomingcontactmsg"></div>
<div class="outgoingcontactmsg"></div>
</div>
```

Since I can have multiple chatboxes, I load the template only once and save it in a javascript string object.

```
template.chatbox=chatboxstring;
```

I have to extract the message templates from within the chatbox template and save them in memory so that I don't query my dom again and again.

```
template.incomingmsg="";
template.outgoingmsg="";
```

To achieve the above I do the following:

```
var a=createElement("div");
a.innerHTML=template.chatbox;

template.incomingmsg=a.querySelector('.incomingmsg').innerHTML;
template.outgoingmsg=a.querySelector('.outgoingmsg').innerHTML;
```

Question 1: Is the above the only way to go about it?

Question 2: I'm saving strings for incoming and outgoing message and wrapping them in a div everytime a message comes.
Which is better? 
a.Keeping a DOM Node saved in a javascript object for it's life time, or 
b.keeping a string(for innerhtml) and parsing it again and again everytime a message is received and sent. I raise the question because NODE object in memory eats more memory than a string object vs on appending string as InnerHtml I'll be repeatedly parsing the same string again.

Answer (score 0):

1)
For handling XML(HTML) in js maybe i wouldn't use pure html dom access and would use some framework for example jQuery (there is more frameworks with diferent performance):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

It is more readeble then using html DOM and innerHTML. And remember that readibility is rly important. if you look at your own code after few months you wont know what is going on.

2) It is good to realize that on client side (browser) you are handling only one client. So Even when there are 20 000 users using your application it is not such a big problem if you are using one or antoher way on CLIENT side. Your performance focus should be on server side.

I would use sollution where i use a little bit more memory and dont have to parse everytime(a).